# How to create a Jenkins like allure report (link to previous reports) using docker image or Gradle plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, allure

At [Allure Jenkins plugin](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_history_files) we are able to keep a historic from previous executions. At the trend graph, I can open previous reports, so I can check, for example, why a test failed at a specific execution.
[Example of trend graph in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxDFy.png)

Can we keep previous reports information and link them at trend graph as Jenkins plugin is doing when creating a report using [Gradle plugin](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_gradle_5) or [docker image](https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service)?
For now, what I am doing is copying the historic folder so I can get the trend, retries... but the previous reports are overwritten. So the information is lost.

Comment: At documentation, it says there is a launches page, how I can enable it? https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_overview_page